# SQL connection issue from sharepoint after messing with service accounts

Tags: sql-server, security, sharepoint, service

**I had** a win7 x64 box with a local Sharepoint 2010 installed on **an SQLEXPRESS** DB.

**Last week I also installed an SQL 2008 R2 instance** with integration and analysis services next to the existing database.

Because I had issues deploying analysis services solutions, **I messed around quite some with the SQL Services Accounts**. Eventually I got it to work and managed to deploy a analysis service solution.

**Today I went back in my local sharepoint and tried to add a new document library. This gave error 0x80131904 which is an SQL error usually related to rights.**

I figure I messed up one (or more) of the services too much and made them incompatible with the sharepoint setup.

I'm no hero when it comes to security and configuration **so I'm asking some advice on things I can try** to solve this issue..

This is a screenshot of the SQL related services that I played around with last week.

[image]

I have already played around with the accounts today but as I said before, I don't really know what I'm doing. I have also tried restarting the app pool and the application in IIS.

Any advice is welcome about which service could cause this problem and what else I can try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my local sharepoint runs on an MS SQL server Express edition and the content database was full.. I had been testing an import of a huge amount of documents.

You can upgrade the database to a full edition or manually run a DELETE statement on tables AllDocs and AllDocStreams.